# libxslt error: lxml on Docker python:3.6.5-alpine3.7

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I've installed the dependences using `apk add libxslt-dev libxml2-dev` for `pip install lxml` successfully, but encountering error with

```
...
Successfully built e6d5e3a0d74b
Successfully tagged 172.16.3.191:5000/spider/parse:1.2
[root@docker-191 Parse]# docker run -p 1000:10002 172.16.3.191:5000/spider/parse:1.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 1, in <module>
    from parsel.selector import Selector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/parsel/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from parsel.selector import Selector, SelectorList  # NOQA
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 8, in <module>
    from lxml import etree, html
ImportError: Error loading shared library libxslt.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

when I run my app.

I don't know what is the matter with Docker image **alpine3.7** or **python 3.6.5** or **python:3.6.5-alpine3.7**?

What should I do? Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: I've finded the problem, `apk del $dependences`, the `libxslt-dev` was deleted mistakenly. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @NLOneday, my Dockerfile had `apk add --virtual build-deps libxslt-dev ...` and in the same RUN command `build-deps` was removed. Moving `libxslt-dev` away from the virtual worked